# Replace a bunch of elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a bunch of divs with javascript.

```js
const ref_link = document.querySelectorAll('.is-field.link');

ref_link.forEach(function (element) {

    const ref_link_content = element.querySelector(".is-field.link .value").innerHTML;
    alert(ref_link_content);

    const ref_link_new = document.createElement('a');
    
    ref_link_new.innerHTML = '<p class="icon"><a href="' + ref_link_content + '">Website</a></p>';
    ref_link.parentNode.replaceChild(ref_link_new, ref_link);
});
```

```html
<div class="is-field link">
  <div class="value">https://link1.com</div>
</div>

<div class="is-field link">
  <div class="value">https://link2.com</div>
</div>

<div class="is-field link">
  <div class="value">https://link3.com</div>
</div>
```

This alerts the first content just fine. But afterwards generates an error message in the console:

```
header.js?ver=1.0:35 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceChild')
    at header.js?ver=1.0:35:21
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at header.js?ver=1.0:27:10
```

The result should look like the following

```html
    <div class="is-field link">
      <p class="link"><a href="https://link1.com">Website</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="is-field link">
      <p class="link"><a href="https://link2.com">Website</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="is-field link">
      <p class="link"><a href="https://link3.com">Website</a></p>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just before the error occurs, what are `this` and `this.parentNode`?

Comment: @mykaf `this` should actually be `ref_link `

Comment: is there a reason why you used `this` instead of the `element` being passed as argument?

Comment: Change your **.is-field.link .value** to just **.value** as that is a child of element

Comment: @cute_programmer that was a mistake. should have been `ref_link` or `element` of course

Comment: You are creating an <a> and you are adding an <a> inside of it?

Comment: you can get the parentNode of all the `.is-field.link` divs outside for each loop. then use it to replace the current element in the loop with the new one.

Comment: You cannot nest `<a>` elements. Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `this.parentNode.replaceChild(ref_link_new, ref_link);`, you are trying to use window and the live html collection. You are not using the element you are referencing.

It should be `element.parentNode.replaceChild(ref_link_new, element);`

You have a bunch of other issues like you are trying to select an element using the selector of the element you have and you are making invalid html with an anchor in an anchor.

Code should just be selecting the divs that have the links and replacing them with the p and a tag. `replaceWith` is easier to use.

```js
const ref_links = document.querySelectorAll('.is-field.link .value');

ref_links.forEach(function (element) {

    const ref_link_new = document.createElement('p');
    ref_link_new.classList.add('icon');  
    
    ref_link_new.innerHTML = '<a href="' + element.textContent + '">Website</a>';
    
    element.replaceWith(ref_link_new);
});
```

```css
.icon::before { 
  content: '\1F517'; 
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="is-field link">
  <div class="value">https://link1.com</div>
</div>

<div class="is-field link">
  <div class="value">https://link2.com</div>
</div>

<div class="is-field link">
  <div class="value">https://link3.com</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I got it :)

```js
const ref_link = document.querySelectorAll('.is-field.link');

ref_link.forEach(function (element) {

const ref_link_content = element.querySelector(".value").innerHTML;
const ref_link_new = document.createElement('p');
ref_link_new.classList.add('icon');

ref_link_new.innerHTML = '<a href="' + ref_link_content + '">Website</a>';
element.parentNode.replaceChild(ref_link_new, element);
});
```